# simplify if-statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$scope.vergleich = function () {
    if ($scope.relrechtsform.indexOf(dataService.dic.alt.rechtsformKanlei || dataService.dic.neu.rechtsformKanlei ) !== -1) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false;                   }
    }
}
```

I am currently student and intelliJ tells me I have to simplify this if-statement but I have no idea how. Maybe somebody can help me.

Comment: You don't need the if just return the condition.

Comment: IntelliJ usually offers to simplify itself, by clicking on the light bulb near the gutter!

Comment: Why is there a `||` inside `indexOf`? Just to be clear, it will check if the first [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value of the 2 expressions exists in `relrechtsform`. It will NOT check if either of the values exists in `relrechtsform`.

Comment: It would have been a good idea to write with your own words what that condition was supposed to check. Just the user is gone as I see.

Answer (score 4):

The simplification is probably that, if `condition` is a boolean, :

```
if (condition) { 
  return true;
} 
else { 
  return false;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
return condition;
```

**However** there also seems to be a logical error in your test.

```
$scope.relrechtsform.indexOf(dataService.dic.alt.rechtsformKanlei ||
                        dataService.dic.neu.rechtsformKanlei ) !== -1
```

Does **not** mean the same thing as :

```
$scope.relrechtsform.indexOf(dataService.dic.alt.rechtsformKanlei) !== -1 || 
$scope.relrechtsform.indexOf(dataService.dic.neu.rechtsformKanlei) !== -1
```

Comment: The second part of your answer [is wrong](https://jsfiddle.net/ulysse_bn/7Lnrv45u/3/) because of how `||` reacts to truthy values.

Comment: @UlysseBN, well, actually, it's not equivalent : 

`const a = [false, "blah"]
console.log(a.includes(1 || "blah") === (a.includes(1) || a.includes("blah")))`

Comment: That is exactly what my example is about ^^.

Comment: @UlysseBN mmm I forgot to write "Not" in my answer, -_-

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
 $scope.vergleich = function () {
  return $scope.relrechtsform.indexOf(dataService.dic.alt.rechtsformKanlei || dataService.dic.neu.rechtsformKanlei ) !== -1;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tân's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893737/6320039) is a correct answer to your question. However, with recent JavaScript you can simplify even more thanks to [`array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
$scope.vergleich = () =>
    $scope.relrechtsform.includes(dataService.dic.alt.rechtsformKanlei || dataService.dic.neu.rechtsformKanlei)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use your condition instead of using `IF else` statement -:

```
$scope.vergleich = function () {
    return ($scope.relrechtsform.indexOf(dataService.dic.alt.rechtsformKanlei ||
                        dataService.dic.neu.rechtsformKanlei ) !== -1);
};
```